# React 18 Strict Mode & Impure Function Component that clears local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm using React 18 and have React.StrictMode enabled.  I have implemented a non-pure function that is executed from the /post-login route that our OIDC Identity Provider calls after a user is authenticated.  The non-pure function:

- retrieves the nonce (and redirect url) from local storage and populates a local 'nonce' variable
- early exits if no nonce exists in local storage and redirects user to login page, as nonce must have been set in local storage before redirecting to Identity Provider for authentication
- clears the nonce from local storage
- extracts the OIDC Id Token sent by the Identity Provider after authentication
- confirms local nonce matches nonce sent back by Identity Provider
- redirects authenticated user to redirect url (or root url)

Here's the exact React functional component code:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { logout } from './auth-redirects';
import localstorage from 'store2';
import client from '../client';

const PostLoginPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const nonce = localstorage('nonce');
  const redirectTarget = localstorage('redirectTarget') ?? '/';

  // NOTE: Cannot remove 'nonce' from local storage here due to Strict Mode
  // The PostLoginPage component may render twice and we need the 'nonce'
  // to still exist in local storage on the second render.
  // Instead - remove the 'nonce' in the RequireAuth component.

  localstorage.remove('nonce');
  localstorage.remove('redirectTarget');

  if (!nonce || !location.hash) {
    logout();
    return;
  }

  // Parse URL hash of format #foo=bar&stuff=things
  const hashQuery = location.hash
    .substring(1)
    .split('&')
    .map(str => str.split('='))
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
      prev[curr[0]] = curr[1];
      return prev;
    }, {});

  if (!hashQuery.id_token) {
    logout();
    return;
  }

  const decoded = JSON.parse(window.atob(hashQuery.id_token.split('.')[1]));

  if (nonce !== decoded?.nonce) {
    logout();
    return;
  }

  localstorage.set('code', hashQuery.code);
  localstorage.set('idToken', hashQuery.id_token);

  client.put('user/set-last-login');

  return <Navigate to={redirectTarget} replace />;
};

export default PostLoginPage;
```

This code is wrapped inside a `React.StrictMode` element, which causes the functional component to be rendered twice (mount->dismount->re-mount).  The issue is that the code clears the nonce from local storage during the first render, so that upon the second render the nonce no longer exists in local storage and the render early exits, redirecting the user back to the login page (via the `logout` function call).

What is the preferred method for making this a pure function, as per the React team's suggestion?

As-is, it does not run in Strict Mode.  My workaround has been to move the code that clears the local storage to the `RequireAuth` component that wraps all components requiring authentication.  But that smells bad to me as I think it should be the responsibility of the `PostLoginPage` component to clear the local storage.

Comment: A little late but maybe this is useful for someone. I had the exact same problem and I could solve it by wrapping the remove functions in a setTimeout like this: `setTimeout(() => localStorage.removeItem('key'), 0)`. It's not ideal, seems a bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just about everything in this component is an ***unintentional*** side-effect. The solution is to move all the logic into one, or more, `useEffect` hooks with appropriate dependency arrays, to be called as an ***intentional*** side-effect.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { logout } from './auth-redirects';
import localstorage from 'store2';
import client from '../client';

const PostLoginPage = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const nonce = localstorage('nonce');
    const redirectTarget = localstorage('redirectTarget') ?? '/';

    localstorage.remove('nonce');
    localstorage.remove('redirectTarget');

    if (!nonce || !location.hash) {
      logout();
      return;
    }

    // Parse URL hash of format #foo=bar&stuff=things
    const hashQuery = location.hash
      .substring(1)
      .split('&')
      .map(str => str.split('='))
      .reduce((prev, curr) => {
        prev[curr[0]] = curr[1];
        return prev;
      }, {});

    if (!hashQuery.id_token) {
      logout();
      return;
    }

    const decoded = JSON.parse(window.atob(hashQuery.id_token.split('.')[1]));

    if (nonce !== decoded?.nonce) {
      logout();
      return;
    }

    localstorage.set('code', hashQuery.code);
    localstorage.set('idToken', hashQuery.id_token);

    client.put('user/set-last-login');
  }, [location, /* and any other missing dependencies the linter complains about */]);

  return <Navigate to={redirectTarget} replace />;
};

export default PostLoginPage;
```

Note that the `useEffect` hook will still be run twice as part of the `React.StrictMode`'s double-mounting to [Ensure Reusable State](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). If this is still an issue then you will need to return a cleanup function from the `useEffect` hook to cancel any pending actions/subscriptions/etc, or rethink the architecture for what the code is doing so logic isn't coupled to component mounting/unmounting.

Comment: Drew - I did originally implement the component with this logic in the callback of the `useEffect` hook, as you have done.  But, as you mentioned, the `useEffect` hook is called twice and the localstorage state is not the same between the two invocations, so the component's response is different and the behavior is the same whether or not I use a `useEffect` callback to manage the side effect.  The only way I could solve this was to move the localstorage state manipulation to _another_ component (`RequireAuth` wrapper component) that _always_ clears these values from localstorage.

Comment: @BryanAmbrogiano That seems to agree with my suggestion to decouple the logic from the mounting/unmounting of this `PostLoginPage` component.